# How to get back the data after Marshal.Copy(byte,0,ptr,len)?

Tags: c#, .net

we have used the foll. code to marshal the byte array - ie:copy to unmanaged memory space;

`Marshal.Copy(byte,0,ptr,len)?`

How do I put the data back into a byte array in another program?

Pls advice if my approach is correct :-

```
string aString = "some text";
        byte[] theBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aString);
// Marshal the managed struct to a native block of memory.
        int myByteSize = theBytes.Length;
        IntPtr pmyByte = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myByteSize ); //this is pointer
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(theBytes, 0, pmyByte , myByteSize );
.............
```

Following this, I would like to retrieve the data with in this unmanaged memory into a string variable, how do I achieve that?

In VB6 I am doing it using (may be helpful for someone who wants to pass data from c#.net to vb6 app):-

```
Call CopyMemory(buf(1), ByVal cds.lpData, cds.cbData)
              a$ = StrConv(buf, vbUnicode)
              a$ = Left$(a$, InStr(1, a$, Chr$(0)) - 1)
              Form1.Print a$
```

**How do I pick up the marshaled data in C#.NET?**

Comment: Are you asking about how to put data into unmanaged memory, or about how to copy memory, pointed by `IntPtr`, back to managed array?

Comment: The question is meaningless if you don't tell us *exactly* how you get the pointer to the data into the other program.  Which invariably is the hang-up, pointer values are strongly tied to the process and are not valid in another process.  There are *many* ways to do process interop in .NET, none of which start with Marshal.Copy().

Comment: The other app is a VB6 app so I am using the wndproc and hooking on to windows messages which I ams ending using sendmessage(p1,p2,p3,p4)

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes, that you know the unmanaged data length (`someArraySize`) and character encoding:

```
// create new managed array
var array = new byte[someArraySize];
// copy data from unmanaged memory, pointed by ptr, into managed array
Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, someArraySize);
// convert array to string; this assumes, that array contains string in UTF-8 encoding
var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
```

Comment: He could use the BSTR approach, and prefix the data with the length.

Comment: @NathanM: He using `Encoding.GetBytes` to pass data into unmanaged memory. I doubt whether he *returns* `BSTR` in this case.

Comment: He could improvise, and prepend the length manually, increment the pointer 4 bytes and then copy the data over.

Comment: Why would that be considered maniacal?  If I had to pass memory to another program, I would probably put it in some form of structure that gave me the ability to determine what it was.

The other option is a simple null term.  Probably the better one, actually.

Comment: OK, is my way of setting the string to byte array, getting size, pointer and calling Marshal.Copy(p1,p2,p3,p4) correct? Am I doing anything incorrect?